# How can I have a subview that is 'tap-through' to the parent view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a subview that is its own View Controller, that covers top 1/3rd of the screen (it is like an informational dialogue that keeps updating) and I want the other 2/3rd of the screen which contains a map and a button to still be a accessible.

This top 1/3rd is a dialogue that only comes up under certain conditions, so it's not always there.

I've made it clear so the user can still see the background, not sure how to make it so the map and button is still accessible.

```
if (exampleCondition) {
            if (view.viewWithTag(10) == nil) {

                let tripStartedViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TripInProgressDialog")

                addChild(tripStartedViewController)
                view.addSubview(tripStartedViewController.view)
                tripStartedViewController.view.tag = 10
                tripStartedViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: could you please post a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: When the dialog is present, events are going to be direct to it rather than the underlying view... You say it's transparent, but that's not how to dismiss a view.   Why not actually hide it, or eliminate it entirely when it's not in use?  Or just make it a regular view as suggested in Matt's answer

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ignore touches on the transparent view but handle them in its subviews and views behind it. To do so I usually override the hit test of a view by subclassing an `UIView`:

```
class TransparentTouchView: UIView {
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let originalHitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        return originalHitView === self ? nil : originalHitView
    }
    
}
```

This code returns `nil` only when exactly "self" was pressed. All other cases will work normally as it was. This way subviews are unaffected.

You can apply this to any view. In your case I assume you need to put this into your `Main` storyboard and define it as a class to main view of  `TripInProgressDialog`.

[image]

**After some comments this is a full working example:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onDidTap)))
        
        let dialogViewController = DialogViewController()
        dialogViewController.willMove(toParent: self)
        self.addChild(dialogViewController)
        dialogViewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(dialogViewController.view)
        dialogViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
    
    @objc private func onDidTap() {
        print("Bottom view tapped")
    }

}

class DialogViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view = TransparentTouchView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
        view.addSubview({
            let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 100))
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onGreenButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }())
    }
    
    @objc private func onGreenButtonPressed() {
        print("Green button pressed")
    }
    
}

class TransparentTouchView: UIView {
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let originalHitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        return originalHitView === self ? nil : originalHitView
    }
    
}
```

Pressing on the button in the dialog will trigger the button action. Tapping anywhere else will trigger the event on the view controller below.

Comment: @Fattie To me the question does not look more complicated than this answer describes. But I agree this could have been handled better on Apple side and we do keep coming back to this same problem over and over again. Custom dialog such as toast messages in messages, picture-in-picture for custom video calls or assistants and more, custom overlay tutorials... I have so far always solved this using the approach above. Subclassing `UIView` and in many cases also `UIWindow`.

Comment: @Fattie Maybe there is something else in your case. Please check the edit I made with a full working example. Or maybe I misunderstood some requirements.

Comment: I will check it out for sure. It looks like you're right.  It used to be that there were other invisible views between (and you had to find them and "transparent -ize them" .. ) could be I'm years out of date!  Good one!

Answer (score 1):

#### The only realistic way to achieve this:

Make a view type, "touch delegating view":

```
///The most tricky thing you will ever see. Deliberately pass touch to the "next" vc: ie, very likely the vc "behind" us visually.
class TouchDelegatingView: UIView {
    weak var touchDelegate: UIView? = nil
    
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        guard let view = super.hitTest(point, with: event) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        guard view === self, let point = touchDelegate?.convert(point, from: self) else {
            return view
        }
        
        return touchDelegate?.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

On your vc, `FrontVC`, in fact (say on the storyboard) change the normal view of the vc to literally be a `TouchDelegatingView`

Next you have the problem, on that view, you have to set the delegate.

You can do that any way you wish, but assuming the vc "behind" is the presenter, a surprisingly easy trick is:

Simply in `viewDidLoad` of the `FrontVC` do this

```
// Need to set the delegate of our .view:
if let delegatingView = view as? TouchDelegatingView {
    delegatingView.touchDelegate = presentingViewController?.view
    // or set it to anywhere relevant to you
    print("test - I set up the touch delegate ok")
}
else {
    print("problem")
}
```

And that's it.

Note that, of course, in simple situations (you're just adding a square of info or such) you don't need to do any of this, or even present another VC. All you do is have a small container view that sits where you want.

However in many situations you realistically need to be able to "go through" to the behind VC.

Comment: That's true: "The most tricky thing you will ever see. Deliberately pass touch to the "next" vc", especially if you are working with UIHostingController and SwiftUI. Just see the reputation numbers of the answerers. Hidden gem, working...

Comment: @BootMaker - i totally agree  :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a presented view controller, then all touches are routed to *this* view and *this* view controller, and *not* to the view controller of the view that is visible behind. There's nothing you can do about that.

If what you wanted was just a view that covers part of the screen and does not prevent the rest of the screen from being touched, then you should have put up a simple view that covers part of the screen, not a whole presented view controller.

(For instance, google "toast" for iOS and look at how toast alerts are generally implemented.)

If you really want to use a separate view controller, then it needs to be a custom child view controller of your main view controller, not a presented view controller. If you go that route, there is an elaborate "child dance" that you have to do in order to make this a true parent-child relationship; make sure you are doing the dance.